cypress support/e2e.ts is running in component mode
I'm trying to add cypress component tests to a code base that already has e2e tests running.
This is my run command:
 npx cypress run --component --browser chrome

It is running support\e2e.ts which has api calls that are not valid in component mode.
I have a minimal component definition in cypress.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import axios from "axios";

export default defineConfig({
  viewportWidth: 1300,
  viewportHeight: 800,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 10000,
  projectId: "o1cjb6",
  screenshotOnRunFailure: true,
  reporter: "junit",

  reporterOptions: {
    mochaFile: "tests/test-output-[hash].xml",
    toConsole: true,
    attachments: true,
  },

  retries: {
    runMode: 2,
    openMode: 0,
  },

  numTestsKeptInMemory: 1,


  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "vue-cli",
      bundler: "webpack",
    },
  },
});


Commenting out the e2e equivalent as an experiment made no difference.
cy.mount which is defined in component.ts is not picked up.
So, how do I force cypress to skip e2e.ts and use component.ts in component mode?

Please show your cypress.config.ts, would like to see where the calls are that are causing the trouble.

Thanks for that - but sorry, I can't reproduce it. For my component test e2e.ts is ignored.

According to docs this should not be the case: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Support-file
Do you have a file cypress/support/component.js or cypress/support/component.ts present? If not have you tried removing the e2e.ts file completely?

import axios from "axios"; looks suspicious + is not needed in the config anyway.

This problem does seem contrary to expectations, however if you wish to add some conditional execution to the code in e2e.ts, the testingType property is available.
if (Cypress.testingType === 'e2e') {
  // perform api for e2e mode testing
}

